# To copy the content of a disabled textbox on click of a button using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, function, web-development-server

I have an angular app, in which I am trying to copy a text on click of a button. I need a function to help me do that. I don't want to use clipboard API.

I have seen the clipboard API but I want to write it in pure typescript

Answer (score 1):

you need the clipboard api to interact with the clipboard, **there is no real way around it**. Typescript is just a fancy layer on top of javascript that compiles to javascript. Browser do not understand TS, they only understand JS.

Typescript should provide autocompletion and typings for the clipboard api already out of the box, if it doesn't then check your `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions.lib`: that key should not exist, or include `"dom"`. For more info on changing what types TS has build in see https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib